# Simple C++ recursion does not work properly - I just don't see why

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a small C++ program which should just sum up the contents of an integer array. The debug output shows that the recursion function is called correctly. I even checked the address of the array - it's the same all over.

I fail to understand why that code puts out this odd number in the end. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't get it. Does anybody have a pointer in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr_sum(int arr[], int idx) {
    // debug
    cout << "arr[" << idx << "] = " << arr[idx] << " (" << arr << ")" << endl;

    if (idx > 0) {
        return arr[idx] + arr_sum(arr, idx - 1);
    }
}

int main () {
    int a[10];
    a[0]=1; a[1]=2;a[2]=3;a[3]=4; a[4]=5;
    a[5]=6; a[6]=7;a[7]=8;a[8]=9; a[9]=0;

    cout << a << endl;   // debug
    cout << "Sum: " << arr_sum(a, 9) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7ffc7c3fc7e0
arr[9] = 0 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[8] = 9 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[7] = 8 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[6] = 7 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[5] = 6 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[4] = 5 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[3] = 4 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[2] = 3 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[1] = 2 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
arr[0] = 1 (0x7ffc7c3fc7e0)
Sum: 6295692
```

Comment: Step through that code with a debugger, the problem will be obvious.

Comment: An `else` makes all the difference.

Comment: What does `arr_sum(arr, 0)` return?

Comment: Question titles should actually state the specific problem behavior, otherwise it's useless for other people.  "recursion doesn't work" is not likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (idx > 0) {
    return arr[idx] + arr_sum(arr, idx - 1);
}
```

you forgot the terminating case

```
if (idx > 0) {
    return arr[idx] + arr_sum(arr, idx - 1);
} else return arr[0];
```

Comment: Uhm.. that should be `else return arr[0];`

Comment: This will leave out the `arr[0]` value from the sum. I think the condition for further recursion should be `idx >= 0`. (OP would have to remove the "debug" output in this case, of course, so as not to access arr[-1].) Or indeed, as @IInspectable says, `return arr[0]` in termination branch.

Comment: @TerraPass: Nope, `idx >= 0` won't work, because the recursive call to arr_sum goes with `idx - 1`.

Comment: @Mark Yes it will, assuming that you don't actually access `arr[-1]` (that is to say, assuming you remove your debug output). Anyway, `else return arr[0]` is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the base case: what does `arr_sum` return if `idx` is zero?

Right now, the function doesn't return anything, which is illegal.  Turn up your compiler warnings, every compiler warns about this.  When it executes, it ends up leaving a random value on the stack, which gets interpreted as the return value, and added to the other results.

Comment: I was afraid it was something so simple. Yes, thanks a lot. Compiler warnings are on, btw (GCC 4.6.3), it seems not to warn for this issue.